# HttpRequestHandler in LWUIT

Tags: lwuit

I'm trying to define a HtmlComponent to open an external link in LWUIT but I found that I need to use HttpRequestHandler when I try to define an object

I can't find this class defined in the LWUIT, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LWUIT see the sample browser application that ships with it.
For CodenameOne use the WebBrowser Component.